# Zend static helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my Bootstrap.php file I have the following code

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    if (null === $viewRenderer->view) 
    {
        $viewRenderer->initView();
    }

    $view = $viewRenderer->view;

    $view->assign('CSS_PATH', 'path/to/css');
```

In layout.phtml I am able to access $this->CSS_PATH but in controllers not. 
So how to access it in any controllers ?

Answer (score 4):

In controllers do

```
echo $this->view->CSS_PATH ;
```